How can I enable hot reloading on a react app with a client side package.json and server side (Express) package.json?
I have a react app with two package.jsons. The frontend currently won't update unless I run npm run build each time... I would like to see my frontend changes instantly without having to rebuild it each time. The frontend is react (v 18.3.1) and the backend is in Express. This is what my codebase structure looks like after I only include the relevant folders/files:
client/
  build/
  src/
  index.tsx
  package.json // client side package.json
  tsconfig.json
server/
dist/
  index.js
index.ts
package.json // server side package.json

client side package.json scripts:
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }

server side package.json scripts:
 "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/index.js\""
}

I've tried tweaking the scripts in my client's package.json file but I still need to run "npm run build" for new changes to appear.
Please let me know if you need any additional information! Thank you for for all of your help!

npm start should start the React dev-server (Webpack) which supports HMR. npm run build just compiles static assets

I have a feeling you're serving the React frontend statically in your Express app. This answer might be what you're after

@Phil thank you for your response. I also think I'm serving my react frontend statically after it's built and don't really know how to change it...
I think this is the culprit here in my server's index.ts:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));

app.get('/*', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));
});

It's pointing to the client's build folder and maybe it needs to point to something else?

There's no "culprit" here since there's nothing actually wrong. Have you read the linked answer? For local development with HMR, you need to run the Webpack dev server with npm start.

@Phil Thank you Phil! You made me realize I was missing a step. I was only running npm run dev on the server side which was loading up the frontend in the browser so I didn't realize I still need to go into the client side and also run npm start to see live changes instead of the static frontend. You saved me so much time! I really appreciate it!
